# Which standard deviation should I use in Student's t-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, mean, population

There is something I'm not understanding about the Student's $t$-test, so I will write here an example to explain my doubt. I will write some considerations about the several steps: feel free to comment them if you think I'm wrong, also in details.

Let's say I know that the mean absolute B-magnitude of the population of elliptical galaxies is $\mu_{pop} = -21.3$ (absolute magnitudes are often negative numbers, and the more negative is the more luminous a galaxy is, but it doesn't really matter here). This value could come from decades of observations of thousand of galaxies or from tested theories (isn't it the same?).

Now I observe a sample of $N_{samp} = 13$ elliptical galaxies, finding a mean magnitude $\bar{x}_{samp} = -20$ with standard deviation $s_{samp} = 0.5$.
So I want to conduct a $t$-test in order to know if this sample is taken from the population. The null hypothesis here is that there is no relation between the two (i.e between the cosmic population of elliptical galaxies and from my observed sample).

The main doubt is: which standard deviation have I to put as denominator in $t$ definition? Given that

$$ t = \frac{| \bar{x}_{samp} - \mu_{pop} |}{\sigma} \, \mbox{,}$$

which $\sigma$ should I use? If I don't know the original (or we can say *true*?) standard deviation of the population $\sigma_{pop}$, I've readen that I can assume that $\sigma_{pop} \simeq s_{samp}/\sqrt{N_{samp}}$. But isn't true that, for $N_{samp} \to \infty$, I should expect $\bar{x}_{samp} \to \mu_{pop}$ and $s_{samp} \to \sigma_{pop}$? For what I've written the paradox is that $s_{samp} \to \sigma_{pop}$ for $N_{samp} \to 1$.

And if have also, as is in the case of my example, the value of $\sigma_{pop} = 1.5$, which $\sigma$ should I put at the denominator of the definition of $t$?

While we're on this topic, I want to test my understanding of the $t$-test: once I have the $t$ value (let's say $t = 2.6$), if I want a 2-tailed test (like in the case of the absolute B-magnitudes of elliptical galaxies) I look in the tables or resolve numerically the integral of $t$ distribution with $\nu = N-1$ degrees of freedom between $-t$ and $+t$. In this example ($t = 2.6$, $\nu = 12$) I find a level of confidence of 97.7%, that is a level of significance (i.e. a $P$-value) of 2.3%. If my significance threshold was $\alpha = 5\%$ the null hypothesis is rejected, then I can say that the sample comes from the population; if instead it was $\alpha = 1\%$ the null hypothesis is not rejected, and I cannot prove it is false (but not even true).

Comment: The t-value is significant at 5%. Then you are making a false conclusion.

Comment: I would maintain that you *don't* want to ask about conducting a t-test.  Your question appears to be about how to compare your 13 galaxies to a large, well-studied population.  By insisting on a t-test you have explicitly ruled out better answers.

Comment: I used maybe a bad example, but I wanted to understand the t-test, not to know about that sample of 13 galaxies wrt the whole population. However, since we're there, if you want to point me to a more correct test for this kind of problems, I'm all ears

Comment: No better  test than t-test exists. From your conversation,  it is clear that you do not have an adequate understanding of  t- statistic. Further you need to edit your question in line with comments.

Comment: @subhashc.davar Your comment requires justification and some kind of assumption that would limit the scope to a case where it's actually true. As a bare statement it's flat out wrong.

Comment: t-statistic equals difference between population  and sample - statistic of say , mean and divided by standard error . If we have sigma we can divide difference by population S.D. (sigma)  and  obtain t-statistic.  IF we do not have true S.D., it can be  estimated with help of  sample estimate of S.D. and size of each sample (n). Sigma estimate is obtained by  dividing S.D of samples 's' by square root of n-size of each of samples. THIS is known as small- samples theory. Large sample (n=30 or more) theory invokes z-statistic. I CAN'T edit question (I am debarred to edit questions.).

Comment: I HAVE presumed that we are dealing with small samples is small samples theory. I shall be glad if I could clarify things which I perceive .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to CrossValidated. I'll try to answer your question to the best of my ability. I'll start off by perhaps restating our data to better understand the formula for our chosen $t$-test.

From my understanding of your description, you've collected a sample of thirteen galaxies, $n = 13$ which have a mean absolute magnitude, $\bar{x}$, of $-20$ and a sample standard deviation, $S_x$ of $.5$.

Based upon previous research, the hypothesized population mean, $\mu$, is $-21.3$, with an unknown standard deviation, $\sigma$.

Yyour hypothesis states that you wish to test whether your sample of galaxies was taken from (sampled from) the population.

> I want to conduct a t-test in order to know if this sample is taken
>   from the population.

I should note that a $t$-test doesn't actually perform this hypothesis test. However, what it can do is test whether the stated population parameter, $\mu$ is likely to be equal to $-21.3$ based upon your sample. Therefore our hypotheses will be as follows:

$h_0, \mu = -21.3$,

$h_1, \mu \neq -21.3$

Since we're testing this hypothesis using one sample, this test is known as the one-sample $t$-test, which has the formula:

$$t = \frac{ \bar{x} - \mu }{S_\bar{x}} \, \mbox{,}$$

Where $S_\bar{x}$, is the standard error associated with the sample which has the formula:

$$S_\bar{x} = \frac{ S_x }{\sqrt{n}} \, \mbox{,}$$

So to answer your question

> which standard deviation have I to put as denominator in t definition?

**TL;DR: You should be using the sample standard error**

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. However my doubt remains: shouldn't I expect, for $n \to \infty$, that $S_{\bar{x}} \to \sigma$?

Comment: As $n \to N$, $S_\bar{x} \to 0$. The fundamental difference in $S_x$ and $S_\bar{x}$ is that the former is the deviation of observations, whereas the latter is the deviation of *sample means*. When your sample is equal to the population, your derived statistic and parameter are identical. Therefore the error in your sampling will be zero. However, when your sampling approach is done with replacement, it will tend only tend toward zero.

Comment: Ok I think I got this point. But I'm wondering, if I increase wildly the number $n$ of the sample size, doesn't it result in a $t$ value very high (also considering that the degrees of freedom $\nu$ are increasing too)? With this considerations ($t$ and $\nu$ very high) I would always get a $P$-value ridicolously small, so I always reject the null hypothesis! Is there something wrong in this considerations?

Comment: The relationship of $n$ and $t$ are such that, the greater sample size, the less standard error - the less standard error, the greater the $t$ statistic.  The $t$-statistic is defined by the degree of difference, standardized (divided by) the standard error. In essence, this means that that we're calculating the value associated with the probability that the difference (or a difference more extreme) is likely to have risen by sampling error. As stated, $S_\bar{x} \to 0$ as $n \to N$, therefore, the more observations we collect, the more certain we are that our sample is unadulterated by error

Comment: Therefore as you've suggested $t$-statistic will increase given that a difference exists in the numerator as the denominator is standardizing this difference by a factor to account for spurious differences.

Comment: Due to the uncertainty in estimating the SD from the sample, I believe your recommendation will be less powerful than the alternative of using the population parameters to construct a prediction interval for the sample mean.

Comment: Last doubt: if I knew the actual population standard deviation $\sigma = 1.5$, I still have to use the $s_{\bar{x}} = s_x/\sqrt{n}$ at the denominator of $t$, right?

Comment: The reason why the standard error for a $t$-test uses $S_\bar{x}$ rather than $\sigma$ in the numerator is we use the sample standard deviation to approximate the population SD. Where $\sigma$ is known we'll substitute it in our formula, thereby giving us a better approximation of standard error $$\sigma_\bar{x} = \frac {\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$. This also implies using a $z$-test rather than a $t$-test. **I should note** that very rarely are parameters **known**. I don't know the full scope of your data but chances are slim observations have been made on billions of galaxies for $\sigma$